# guia para poder hacer una app basica en android studio

Tags: android-studio

vengo a pedirles algo de ayuda, verán, apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar Android studio y quiero hacer un especie de test de tal forma que al responder una pregunta los botones "verdadero y falso" se inhabiliten para esa pregunta pero no se me ocurre como, también necesito que al inhabilitarlas me cuente las correctas e incorrectas para al final mostrarlas con otro toast.

hasta ahora simplemente tengo un text que va a cambiar de pregunta cuando se presione el mismo texto, el botón siguiente o anterior y a su vez dos botones verdadero o falso, que mostrarán un toast que dirá correcto o falso dependiendo de su pregunta, este es el código que llevo en el Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private ImageButton mPrevButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
     int Respuestas_correctas;
     int Respuestas_incorrectas;

    private Question[] mBancoPreguntas = new Question[]{
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceania, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_medio_oriente, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_america, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        int question = mBancoPreguntas[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);


        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /**
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                View vi = toast.getView();
                vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                toast.show();
                */

                mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
                checkAnswer(true);

            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /**
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                View vi = toast.getView();
                vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                toast.show();
                 */

                mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
                checkAnswer(false);


            }
        });

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = mCurrentIndex + 1;
                int question = mBancoPreguntas[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
                mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = mCurrentIndex + 1;
                int question = mBancoPreguntas[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
                mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

            }
        });

        mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = mCurrentIndex - 1;
                int question = mBancoPreguntas[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(false);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(false);
                mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

            }
        });

    }
    private void checkAnswer (boolean userPressTrue){
        boolean answerTrue = mBancoPreguntas[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if (userPressTrue == answerTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
            Respuestas_correctas++;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, -300);
            View vi = toast.getView();
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
            Respuestas_incorrectas++;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, -300);
            View vi = toast.getView();
            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Este es el codigo que llevo en Question:

```
public class Question {
    private int mTextResId;
    private boolean mAnswerTrue;


    public Question(int TextResId, boolean AnswerTrue) {
        mTextResId = TextResId;
        mAnswerTrue = AnswerTrue;

    }

    public int getTextResId() {
        return mTextResId;
    }

    public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
    }

    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
        return mAnswerTrue;
    }

    public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
}
```

y estos son los que tengo en strings:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
    <string name="question_australia">Camberra es la capital de australia</string>
    <string name="question_oceania">El oceano pacifico es más largo que el oceano atlantico</string>
    <string name="question_medio_oriente">el canal de suezia conecta el mar rojo y el océano índico</string>
    <string name="question_africa">la fuente del río nilo está en egipto</string>
    <string name="question_america">el río amazonas es el río más largo de américa</string>
    <string name="question_asia">el río amazonas es el río más largo de américa</string>

    <string name="next_button">Siguiente</string>
    <string name="prev_button">Anterior</string>
    <string name="true_button">Verdadero</string>
    <string name="false_button">Falso</string>
    <string name="correct_toast">Correcto</string>
    <string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrecto</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? ¿Qué has depurado? ¿Qué errores tienes?

Comment: @A.Cedano no tenía un error, quería que me ayudarán a solucionar el problema que tenía pero ya lo hice, ahora solo me falta que el programa no se me reinicie al rotar la pantalla.